# IE9 not saving session data

Tags: session, cookies, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem with saving session data with IE9. When users login the session is saved correctly. Now, if they browse through the application, the application stores the pagehistory into the session data (I use this for the applications back button). Unfortunately IE9 does not always save this data into the session (sometimes it does and sometimes it does not). It works perfectly with other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP, try adding a header like:

```
//vfranchi - necessary to IE8, so it won't throw a warning
header('P3P:CP="This site does not contain a P3P policy."');
```

I think this is related to IE8 not saving cookie information when the site doesn't have a explicit privacy policy. I had the same problem and that fixed for me.

Remember this statement needs to be before any output just like session_start()

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by switching off IE8 compatibility mode.